# Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have a new Ubuntu install where I am not able to connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 or using my computer name.

```
telnet localhost [tried all/no port numbers]
```

returns

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Is there any configuration I need to do to make this work? Would it be disabled by default??

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure telnetd is running?

```
sudo apt-get install telnetd
```

Comment: telnet is working.

Comment: just wander what @pb2q changed in my post

Comment: @RomanNewaza you can click the _edited ... ago_ to see the edit history of any post: I simply changed a typo: you had _telned_

Comment: @user1076371: "telnet is working"?!?  What about the "connection refused"??????  Please follow Roman Newaza's advice (which is *good* advice!), and please look at my link (of which "install telnetd" is a part).

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is "telnet" enabled?

If it isn't, or if your iptables firewall is configured to block telnet, then you'll get exactly this error :)  Try "`apt-get install telnetd`".

And *don't* try to "telnet" except on your local LAN - it's *NOT* secure!!!!  Always use SSH instead.

This link might help:

- http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux